# Using devise login as root calls separate root in an infinite loop and causes " url redirected you too many times"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

After logging the user in, then closing the page and reopening the page is redirected too many times. The rails terminal shows an infinite call of the following two routes to each other, but I can't figure out why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xx at 2019-07-20 20:52:11
Started GET "/" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xx at 2019-07-20 20:52:12
```

Changing the root from the devise login fixes the issue, but this isn't desirable.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: "sessions"}
  root :to => redirect("/users/sign_in")
  post 'pindex', to: 'locker#index'
  get 'view',   to: 'locker#view'
  post 'view', to: 'locker#many_new'
  match 'sort/:type', to: 'locker#sort', :via => :get, :as => :sort
  resources :locker
 end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
 class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    if !session[:return_to].blank?
     redirect_to session[:return_to]
      session[:return_to] = nil
    else
      respond_with resource, :location => locker_index_path
     end
   end
 end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: 
 session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    </span>
     <%= f.email_field :email,
     class: "form-control", 
     placeholder: "Email Address",
     required:"required"%>  
    </span>
    <%= f.password_field :password, 
      class: 'form-control',
      placeholder: "Password",
      required:"required"%> 
     <%= f.submit "Log In", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg"%>
 <%end%>
```

Comment: Try to set `root :to => redirect("/users/sign_in")` to something else.

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: Yes, sorry I upvoted but I didn't realize my upvotes don't show yet. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you can't upvote you can still click the check icon to mark my answer as correct :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of Devise you can see that in `SessionsController` they call `require_no_authentication` before `new`.

```
prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create]
```

And this method redirects to `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` if the user is signed in. `after_sign_in_path` by default is `root_path` which you redirect to `sessions#new`. So here is your infinite loop.

```
if authenticated && resource = warden.user(resource_name)
  flash[:alert] = I18n.t("devise.failure.already_authenticated")
  redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

To solve it you should override `after_sign_in_path_for` in your `SessionsController` with something else than `root_path`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(_resource_or_scope)
  locker_index_path # or anything you want
end
```